# Как вывести одну русскую букву в массиве $text[1]?

Tags: php

Если вывести весь массив то все ок, а 1 символ то получаю кракозябру. Как исправить? И почему так происходит.

```html
<?php
$text = "абвгд";
print_r($text[1]);
```

Я получаю �

Comment: [смотреть код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/515c7a27ffdeafa080a272fba88cd745ecbc3f64)

Comment: один символ может занимать более 1 байта https://repl.it/repls/HopefulAzureRabidsquirrel

Comment: `И почему так происходит` -  http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.mbstring.php .......`Как исправить?` - использовать функции для работы с многобайтными строками  http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 2):

Это из-за того, что многобайтовая кодировка.
Попробуй mb_substr($text,0,1);

```
mb_substr("абвгд",0,1);
//выведет а
```

Для кругозора http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php